# Openlayers 3 popup on mouseover on marker

Tags: mouseover, marker, openlayers-3

How to display marker details on mouseover with Openlayers 3 ? There is number of examples for older openlayers, but I can't adopt them for Openlayers 3.

Answer (score 4):

You can listen to the map 'pointermove' event to look for features at the pixel location then display the details in the fashion you want.

This example shows how it is done: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.4.0/examples/vector-layer.html